# Symbolic integration of SphericalBesselJ

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, backslide

**Backslide introduced in v10 and persisting through v10.3.1.**

---

Consider the following integral

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Integrate[k^(n) SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k], {k, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0}]]
```

On my machine Mathematica 10.3.1 (Linux version) can do it in roughly 20 seconds

```
{19.7088, 
 ConditionalExpression[(
  Sqrt[π] 2^(n - 1) R^(-n - 1) Gamma[1/2 (l + n + 1)])/Gamma[
  1/2 (l - n + 2)], Re(n) < 1 ∧ l + Re(n) > -1]}
```

Since for my purpose `n` is an integer, one would think that specifying this condition in the assumptions will make it easier for *Mathematica* to solve the integral. Right? Apparently not! For

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Integrate[k^(n) SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k], {k, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0, n ∈ Integers}]]
```

I obtained

```
{69.0534, 
 Integrate[k^n SphericalBesselJ[l,k R], {k, 0,  ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0, n ∈ \!\(\*
TagBox["\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]", Function[{}, Integers]]\)}]}
```

i.e. now Mathematica failed to solve my integral. Is this a bug or I'm missing something about [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) for symbolic integration?

EDIT (3.01.2016): According to WRI this is not a bug/backslide but merely a timing issue. As pointed out by @bbgodfrey, one can avoid this behavior by using `Integrate` together with `TimeConstrained`.

Comment: So should I add the bug tag and report this to WRI? To me, this behavior doesn't seem to be quite ok...

Comment: I think this should be called a backslide. In v9.0.1 both of the 2 samples give the correct result (The latter is still slower though ): http://i.stack.imgur.com/SYKrv.png

Comment: Ok, I've just sent a bug report to WRI with a link to this question. Let's see what they will say.

Comment: It's now CASE:3500395, although the backslide has not been confirmed yet.

Comment: @vsht  I am not sure that timing out a bit sooner constitutes a bug.  Please see the most recent edit to my answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey You are right. I updated my question to include WRI's statement.

Comment: @xzczd: Since it is officially not a bug, could you please remove the backslide header?

Comment: @vsht Well, "backslide" is just a tag (coined by me) to mark those backslides/backsets/degenerations/degradations/regressions/retrogressions in newer versions of _Mathematica_ and I think this issue definitely fits into this category. I guess WRI just claimed it's not a bug, right?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, according to them it is not a bug. As a workaround they suggest to use `TimeConstrained[Integrate[...], Infinity] `, that's it.

Comment: Although WRI refused to accept this behavior as a bug, it seems that they fixed it in v. 11.1. For this example `Integrate` with assumptions is 40% faster than without. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible variants of `Assumptions` here, including

```
AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[k^n SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k], {k, 0, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0, n ∈ Reals}]]
(* {4.00979075897103, ConditionalExpression[
    (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi]*R^(-1 - n)*Gamma[(1 + l + n)/2])/Gamma[(2 + l - n)/2], 
    n < 1 && l + n > -1]} *)
```

or

```
AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[k^n SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k], {k, 0, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0, -1 - l < n < 1}]]
(* {11.002235487576527, 
    (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi]*R^(-1 - n)*Gamma[(1 + l + n)/2])/Gamma[(2 + l - n)/2]} *)
```

or

```
AbsoluteTiming[Integrate[k^n SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k], {k, 0, ∞}, 
    Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0, (n | l) ∈ Integers}]]
(* {4.107987620241559, ConditionalExpression[
    (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi]*R^(-1 - n)*Gamma[(1 + l + n)/2])/Gamma[(2 + l - n)/2], 
    n <= 0 && l + n >= 0]} *)
```

All works sometimes and not others.  The latter two seem faster and more reliable, however.

**Addendum**

A work-around is to run the same `Integrate` two or three times in succession.  I have posted a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102999/1063) about this strange behavior, in the hope of gaining more insight.

**Solution**

From comments made on the question referenced above, it has become apparent that `Integrate` times out after 60 seconds when attempting to do many of the integrals above when called the first time.  The solution is to give it more time.  For instance,

```
TimeConstrained[
    Integrate[k^n SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k], {k, 0, ∞}, 
        Assumptions -> {l > 0, R > 0, n ∈ Integers}], 120] // AbsoluteTiming
```

returns with the correct answer after about 70 seconds.

Comment: Strange, your first example fails for me in the same way as when `n` is an integer. Do you also have version 10.3.1?

Comment: @vsht  Stranger yet, with a fresh session of Mathematica (10.3.0 on Windows 10, 64 bit) which instances return unevaluated depends on the order in which these instances are evaluated!  I need to give this more thought.

Comment: @vsht  I ran many different sets of `Assumptions` and found that the order in which they are run, as well as how many times a particular one is run, affects which return evaluated.  I have added a not particularly satisfying work-around to my answer and also posted a new question illustrating some of the erratic results.

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises in trying to determine the conditions for which the integral is defined. Using `GenerateConditions -> False` provides a solution with the additional assumption and is much faster.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Assuming[{l > 0, R > 0, Element[n, Integers]},
  Integrate[
   k^n SphericalBesselJ[l, R*k],
   {k, 0, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> False]]]

(*  {0.364262, (2^(-1 + n)*Sqrt[Pi]*
        R^(-1 - n)*Gamma[
          (1/2)*(1 + l + n)])/
     Gamma[(1/2)*(2 + l - n)]}  *)
```

Comment: True, but I actually find `GenerateConditions` quite useful, since when working with special functions one often gets results that are correct only in a limited range of the input parameters.

Comment: @vsht - I agree in general that `GenerateConditions -> True` is preferred; however, in this specific case (i.e., including the additional assumption) the choice was between  `GenerateConditions -> False` and an unevaluated expression.